# Odin not allowing firmware to be flashed

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, device-firmware, rom-flashing, odin

I'm following the instructions here to try and upgrade the firmware to I9000XWJS8:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=846913

As soon as I hit start it does nothing, as you can see in the message window it says it's failed. It does this with JS8 or with the Gingerbread download, in Odin 1.7 and 1.3.

What's going wrong? Also, should the phone be in USB debugging mode or regular? I've tried both to no effect.

[image]

Comment: What phone model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phone should be in Download mode:

1. Take out the battery
2. Plug into USB (apparently skip this if you have an i9000 -- see comments)
3. While holding both volume buttons (Note, you may need to hold Home+VolDown instead)

   1. Insert the battery
   2. Click the power button
4. Phone should go into Download mode after a few seconds:

[image: Download mode]

You may need to disconnect from and reconnect it to the computer after this for Odin to see it.

Comment: Additionally, I've heard the phone should be in USB Debugging mode but I don't see how that could affect Download mode since the OS is not running in that mode.

Comment: According to: http://www.prlog.org/10807241-how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-i9000part.html to enter Download mode in I9000 you press "Home key and power key and volume down key" (which I can confirm on a slightly different model, on Samsung Galaxy Spica i5700). And on my model, the phone must be unplugged to enter download mode, otherwise it boots to Android. Also, this is probably a better tutorial than xda-developer, as it has photo of how download mode looks like: http://androidadvices.com/update-samsung-galaxy-s-gt-i9000-to-froyo-xwjs5-2-2-1/

Comment: @Lie Interesting ... I recall now about the Home key, but I've always heard that without USB it won't go into download mode.  I guess it's just another random difference between the international version and the US versions.